# Difficulty facing horses/ difficulty horses facing

Tags: verbs

> The difficulty facing horses was in reallocating the huge numbers displaced by technology to places where they could still be of use.

My question is that in the above sentence it seems to me that difficulty was facing something or " horses" is the subject here .Shouldn't it be - The difficulty horses were facing was in reallocating..../ The difficulty horses facing was in allocating ...?

Comment: It's not a very good sentence any way you phrase it, because it wasn't really the *horses* who faced the difficulty, it was the people who worked with and owned the horses.  So it doesn't much matter how you rearrange the words, the sentence will still be awkward.  Perhaps you could post a link to the source of the quote?

Comment: I think this is an example of *whiz-deletion*.  Would it help you understand the sentence better if it were rephrased as "The difficulty *which was* facing the horses was..."?  As Andrew points out, it's not a very good sentence, though, because it wasn't the horses who were trying to reallocate anything.

Comment: You can omit the "facing" phrase entirely: *The difficulty was in reallocating  the huge numbers of horses displaced by technology to places where they could still be of use.*

Comment: @Andrew Linguistically you are right - but I can't agree that the humans were in a more difficult place than the horses - the majority of whom would undoubtedly have been shot for dog meat. The author, in my view is trying to be too clever in using the word "facing". I would get rid of that altogether and re-phrase as *The difficulty as regards horses, was in reallocating...*

Answer (score 0):

"The difficulty facing horses..." makes difficulty the subject.  In this context, "facing" has a feeling similar to "challenging".

Your first alternative ("The difficulty horses were facing...") is also correct, and "facing" has a feel like "heading toward" and/or "being forced to confront".

Your second alternative ("The difficulty horses facing...") doesn't work within normal English grammar, because the word order isn't correct.

Keep in mind that in the original sentence the difficulty is facing the horses.